# Cant get the SUBMIT box to show under text-box

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem with that the "submit" box doesent show right under the "Password-input". So I wondered if you could help me. Thanks for any answers. Im not a professional programmer so keep that in mind.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
1.8.1.min.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">

.form-field{
 clear:both;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 400px;
 
}
.form-field label {
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: right;
}
.form-field input{
 float: right;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
 
}
#submit{
 text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-field">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Log In: </legend>
  <div>
   <label for="username">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="Uname">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </div>
   <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey its very simple

```
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
```

make an empty label for submit button

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'br' tag which is nothing but new line. Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
1.8.1.min.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">

.form-field{
 clear:both;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 400px;
 
}
.form-field label {
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: right;
}
.form-field input{
 float: right;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
 
}
#submit{
 text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-field">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Log In: </legend>

  <div>
   <label for="username">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="Uname">
  </div>
<br>
<br>
  <div>
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </div>
<br>
<br>
   &nbsp;<input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
<br>
<br>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps for u!!

Comment: @Den Try to accept the question if your problem is solved.Because it may be useful for others